# ResaveAllElements task generates fatal error after adding locale

Tags: localization, php

After adding a new locale to the site, the `ResaveAllElements` task started going off, and after a while stopped progressing. When i checked the logs it said:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in .../craft/app/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php on line 694
```

I thought the point of tasks and subtasks was to prevent this thing from happening, but i might have misunderstood how it actually works.

Unfortunately i have little to no control over the server configs (apache and php). 
**How can i work around this problem**?

Craft Pro 2.3.2644

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

PHP 5.4.36

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the point of tasks and subtasks was to prevent this thing from happening,

No, a task is just another PHP request subject to the same environmental limitations as any other PHP request.  It just so happens that it runs asynchronously in the background.

I assume you don't have access to a php.ini file to increase values?  You can also try via [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php).

Comment: Thanks Brad, but this is also restricted - ".../htdocs/.htaccess: php_value not allowed here". I also tried to increase the time in index.php, but no effect. Seems my only option is to contact the people with access to do this.